# How to display Products Images on Category Products

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, category-products

How can I show products images on category products page?

[image]

Comment: Refer http://inchoo.net/magento/show-product-thumbnail-in-grids/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this link: http://inchoo.net/magento/show-product-thumbnail-in-grids/

There is one small change you will require to a file in above module or it may give you `Image file was not found` error.

Open **app\code\local\Inchoo\Thumbnail\Block\Adminhtml\Template\Grid\Renderer\Image.php** file and update `render` function with below code.

```
public function render(Varien_Object $row)
{
    try{
      $val = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($row, 'thumbnail')->resize(97);
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
      $val = Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl('images/catalog/product/placeholder/image.jpg',array('_area'=>'frontend'));  
    }
    $out = "<img src=". $val ." width='97px'/>";
    return $out;
}
```

Images will be displayed as per below screenshot.
[image]

To add edit link on grid, updated below file.
**app\code\local\Inchoo\Thumbnail\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Category\Tab\Product.php**

Add below code just before `return parent::_prepareColumns();`

```
$this->addColumn('action',
    array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Action'),
        'width'     => '50px',
        'type'      => 'action',
        'getter'     => 'getId',
        'actions'   => array(
            array(
                'caption' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Edit'),
                'url'     => array(
                    'base'=>'adminhtml/catalog_product/edit',
                    'params'=>array('store'=>$this->getRequest()->getParam('store'))
                ),
                'field'   => 'id'
            )
        ),
        'filter'    => false,
        'sortable'  => false,
        'index'     => 'stores',
));
```

Comment: The image display here. https://snag.gy/1AYavQ.jpg ...... I want images should display  https://snag.gy/XT9AIU.jpg

Comment: How to configure products images display in category products https://snag.gy/XT9AIU.jpg

Comment: @zus, please install the module and it will add images where you require. Please check screenshot. Download module from https://github.com/sambolek/thumbnail-grid

Comment: Yeh, its working.

Comment: I did not understand you there. Can you explain in more details? @zus

Comment: Is possible can i export the products like what are all the products i selected          https://snag.gy/aXy9ZV.jpg

Comment: You can add edit link there but exporting products from category will require a lot of code changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65173/discussion-between-zus-and-jaimin-sutariya).

Comment: okay, how can I add edit here?

Comment: could you pls help me https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/215022/57334